# Send data to url in ruby ​on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem, I want to send a json that I have to a URL and this is an action in my controller, I want to get this json in my js by means of an http get, the problem is that I do not understand very well how to do it.
All_events is a method in my helper that returns a json

The action of my controller with the data I want to send

```
def events_calendar
  render json: {events: all_events}
end
```

In my routes.rb:

```
resources :tools do
      collection do
        get 'events_calendar' => 'tools#events_calendar'
      end
    end
```

My js:

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "/admin/tools/events_calendar"
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function (response) {
    });
```

When I execute this, this is the result:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to solve this error?

Comment: what is the error ? I don't see any error in your post

Comment: I think you don't have an error, just a problem to understand it how to works, isn't it?

Comment: I do not have an error, I just need help to solve my problem

Comment: what is your problem ? `events_calendar` method is sending back events data, what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

You need an AJAX call:

```js
$.getJSON('/admin/tools/events_calendar', function(response) {
 console.log(response)
});
```

Please, check the [Working with JavaScript in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) guide.